# Extrude from two shapes

Tags: extrude

I wonder if it's possible to extrude in blender not only from one but two shapes. One shape would be the lateral cut in the Y-Z direction, one shape would be the lateral cut in the X-Z direction.

My source shapes are paths from Adobe Illustrator (.svg). 
E.g. I have two rounded rectangles (same height, different width) as source shapes and want to create a cuboid with rounded edges and corners out of it.
See the source paths here:

[image]
How could I achieve that?

Comment: In fact you want to make some kind of dice ? Starting from these svg to obtain it is mandatory for you ?

Comment: The shapes are more complex than my example.

Comment: How do you want them to mix for an extruded (so intersection) point ?

Comment: That would require a rather complex script

Answer (score 1):

A way to do it would be to convert both shapes to meshes (with Alt+C). Then extrude first mesh of a value greater than wideness of second mesh, and extrude second mesh of a value greater than wideness of first mesh. Then do a boolean intersect of them and a remove double (that can help to obtain a clean result). 
You can't do booleans on extruded curves, even if you add first a remesh modifier on them, so you can't keep the editable property of bezier curves (or svg) for modifying on the fly the final volume if this is what you expected... (But for sure that would be a really great way to do it)

Comment: Thanks. I tried it but unfortunately the boolean intersection creates weird results. E.g. two intersected round edges (like in my example) don't intersect really well.

Comment: Yes it is not really clean for sure. Have you thought of a third party software like freecad to generate the volume, then export to obj and import in blender ? Because the thing you want to do is well handled by parametric modelers.

Answer (score 0):

**Booleans**

For arbitrary shapes you can use the boolean modifier, if you set the threshold to 0.000000 it can even generate nice results in geometry with overlapping faces (sometimes). A further boolean operation with an XY plane would be needed to get rounded corners. This does require that you start from a Mesh rather than an imported SVG/Curve. That will give varying degrees of success.

[image]

**Bevel... just Bevel**

Make a Cuboid, select all faces and hit Ctrl+B, then use mouse wheel to adjust segment count and "mouse distance travelled" to set the radius. If you want precise input of radius and segment count look at the properties display at the bottom of the 3dview - you can type a number directly to get the radius (offset) and press S to start typing the number of segments.

[image]

**Add-ons**

Alternatively for a rounded cuboid, you could use a dedicated addon for that. [Rounded Cube](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Add_Mesh/Add_Round_Cube) by phymec. That way you can give corners radius control, parametrically for the lifetime of the operator.

https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?348741

[image: img rounded cube]

Sverchok also has a rounded cube node (uses the same code as the Rounded Cube add-on)